# Run selected file as maven test in Intellij

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, junit

Is there a way to configure Intellij to run the current selected file with maven test, eg pick from the given context what maven module the file resides and what the current class is.

Right now I setup a Run/Debug configuration for every class I need to run the tests on and the list is quite extensive now. But I think there really should be a better way that my Googling skills fails to inform me about. :-)

Comment: Not sure if I get this question correctly, but you can right click the class in the project view and select *Run FooBarTest* or hit CTRL+SHIFT+F10 somewhere in your test class and it will be run as a test. I.e. You don't have to create run configurations, they will be created automatically. Is that what you want? If it is, I will post it as an answer.

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt  It doesn't seems to work with the maven project. Seems to run a make-script. So the maven-context seems to be lost. I think I need to tell IntelliJ to run with a specific configuration, but I would like this configuration to be context-aware.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37570444/intellij-how-to-create-context-sensitive-maven-shortcuts